# Connecting Arduino with eth0 while leaving wlan0 for Internet

Tags: wireless, ethernet, ifconfig, arduino

I have a simple Arduino HTTP Server and I want to browse this server from my Ubuntu.

If I assign to Arduino an IP 192.168.0.9 and I connect the Arduino HTTP Server to my router (to any of the 4 ethernet ports), all works fine and I can browse from my Ubuntu
   **Ubuntu => wlan0 => router => Arduino HTTP Server**
I assume all is ok because I assigned a static IP to Arduino, and so it sits in the same subnet 192.168.0.0/24.

In my notebook there is also an eth0. It is much easier for me to connect Arduino to this eth0 than to the router.
From `ifconfig`, I have `wlan 192.168.0.22` and `eth0 10.42.0.1`

My goal is to have:
  **Ubuntu => wlan0 => router => Internet**
  **Ubuntu => eth0 =>  Arduino HTTP Server**

To connect Ubuntu to Arduino I have:

- assigned Arduino HTTP servier an IP in the same subnet of the eth0: 10.42.0.9
- added route all request to 10.42.0.9 via eth0
- left route all other request via wlan

But at the moment it is not working.

```
$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.42.0.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

I didn't add the 10.42.0.0... Ubuntu decided this address for the eth0

Can you explain the correct way to use both eth0 and wlan?

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1a:4b:8c:38:8e  
          inet addr:10.42.0.1  Bcast:10.42.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21a:4bff:fe8c:388e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:87 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:13231 (13.2 KB)
          Interrupt:22 Memory:e4600000-e4620000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:2968 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2968 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:386864 (386.8 KB)  TX bytes:386864 (386.8 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1a:73:e5:74:72  
          inet addr:192.168.0.22  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2a02:678:1be:1900:4947:bdbb:4d8b:4c2a/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2a02:678:1be:1900:21a:73ff:fee5:7472/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::21a:73ff:fee5:7472/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:42689 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:20397 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:22666151 (22.6 MB)  TX bytes:3533575 (3.5 MB)
```

Comment: Ubuntu configures these things automatically and everything you posted is both normal and it appears to be working as you envision. Your question is thus unclear, what makes you think you have a problem or that it is not working ? What makes you think your ethernet would work if it were not connected to a router, that makes no sense.

Comment: Are you trying to route from a source on the WAN network thru to to LAN network? Or simply access the arduino from the the Ubuntu? you should be able to ping the arduino from the Ubuntu, as per your route rules show. But to route thru from WAN to LAN you will need somethung like iptable rules to foward.

Answer (score 1):

I just added a line to iptables:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -s 0.0.0.0/0 -d 10.42.0.9 -j ACCEPT
```

now all is fine!